# How to access innerText of HTML tag inside a <TD> tag

Tags: html, excel, html-parsing, excel-2003, vba

I would like to get some text from a web page containing this. I want to have the piece of information with the href="#spec_Brand".

```
<td class="table_spec">
    <dl>
        <dt class="table_spec_title">
            <a class="href_icon href_icon_help table_spec_titleimg" title="Which manufacturer is producing the product?" href="#spec_Brand">
                <span>Brand</span>
            </a>
            <span class="table_spec_titletext">Brand</span>
        </dt>
        <dd class="table_spec_definition">
            Producer of the product?
        </dd>
    </dl>
</td>
```

I'm trying to use:

```
Set TDelementsA = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")
    While r < TDelementsA.Length
      If TDelementsA.className = "table_spec" Then
         Sheet4.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = TDelement.innerText
    End If
```

but it gives me:
Brand
Producer of the product?

In stead of

## spec_Brand

Can someone help me?

Comment: You swap from `TDelementsA` in the `Set`, `While` and `If` lines  to `TDelement` when you actually write to the worksheet. Hopefully just a typo here and not in the actual code

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying? (**Note**: *I stored the above html in Cell A1 of Sheet1 for testing*). Also I am using Late Binding with IE

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim links As Variant, lnk As Variant

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "About: Blank"

    ie.document.body.innerhtml = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Set links = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each lnk In links
        If lnk.classname = "href_icon href_icon_help table_spec_titleimg" Then
            Debug.Print lnk.innertext
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as stated I'm looping through the TD elements. A 2 column table and the left column of the table has the text hidden inside tags and the right column the innerText is what I want. So I was using the TD tag. But I guess I could loop through the table 2 times, for column one searching for <a>-tags and for column two searching for <td>-tags; Although I want to understand if and how I can access, the tags within tags.