# efficient search methods for getElementsByTagName("a")

Tags: excel, html-parsing, excel-2010, vba

I got 1000s of rows of URLs and for each row I am using:

```
For i = 2 to last row
Set links = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each lnk In links
If lnk.innertext = "something" then
do something
end if
Next lnk
Next i
```

a method coomonly used, I guess, and as a ref shown by Sid's code at [How to access innerText of HTML tag inside a <TD> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654430/how-to-access-innertext-of-html-tag-inside-a-td-tag/12654790#12654790)

Is `For loop (the one for each lnk)`, pretty much the only method in this scenario or are there faster efficient methods?
MATCH is probably used only for sheet ranges, but tried it anyways.  It runs w/o error, does nothing and takes the same time as the `For loop` method.  I think it does nothing due to the lack of appropriate addressing in :

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("something", Range("A1:A100"), 0))  'normally used for ranges
If Not IsError(Application.Match("something", links.innertext, 0))  'what I tried
```

Comment: The inner loop you have is pretty much how you do it: the only way to speed things up would be if you had some way to select only a subset of the links, based (eg) on some particular CSS class or other attribute.  What's the purpose of your outer `i` loop here?

Comment: @TimWilliams We truely live in a quantun entangled world - i just tetsted your code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754096/matching-values-in-string-array - and was getting hopeful on saving some good macro time if I can write a function at least for my inner loop - when I saw your response :>)
The outer i loop is for going to next row until LR

Comment: @TimWilliams The inner loop has a few conditions and sequences:
if corresponding cell in column F = "", then
if lnk.innertext = (searchstring1) then put that lnk & innertext in cell column F & G, exit inner loop and go to next outer i loop - row(i).
Repeat for some more searchstrings, INSTR and other search conditions as long as cell in column F = "".

Comment: Still unsure what you're doing: are you searching the same collection of links against a bunch of rows?  Then at least do the `Set links` line before starting the outer loop.